# Login as a specific user with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I am trying to spec the following.

I need to return all entities that are linked to the logged in user. Subsequently I need to create the user before the fact and then ensure that the specific user is logged in. I am struggling to achieve this with controller macros. My specs are failing as follows

1) Yougov::Surveys::ProfilesController GET :index returns all profiles linked to the loged in user with the same country and client as the linked survey
     Failure/Error: sign_in user

```
 RuntimeError:
   Could not find a valid mapping for nil
 # /Users/donovan.thomson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@insight-app/gems/devise-2.2.8/lib/devise/mapping.rb:42:in `find_scope!'
 # /Users/donovan.thomson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@insight-app/gems/devise-2.2.8/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:46:in `sign_in'
 # ./spec/support/controller_macros.rb:17:in `block in login_specific_user'
```

So a basic scaffolding of my controller looks as follows :

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render json: Profile.where(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

I assume this means the user is not being logged in as I would expect

My spec is as follows

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ProfilesController, type: :controller do

  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    @profile = FactoryGirl.create :profile, user: @user
    FactoryGirl.create :profile
  end

  describe "GET :index" do

    login_specific_user(@user)

    it "returns all profiles linked to the loged in user with the same country and client as the linked survey" do
      get :index
      expect(response.body).to eq(@profile.to_json)
    end
  end

end
```

My controller macro's are as follows:

```
    module ControllerMacros

  def login_admin
    before :each do
      sign_in ControllerMacros.get_user(@request, :admin, :admin_user)
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before :each do
      sign_in ControllerMacros.get_user(@request, :user)
    end
  end

  def login_specific_user(user)
    before :each do
      sign_in user
    end
  end

  class << self

    def get_user(req, mapping, type=mapping)
      req.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[mapping]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(type)
      user.confirm!
      user
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by not using controller macros and just adding the following to my before block

```
before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    @user.confirm!
    sign_in @user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **spec/support/devise.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
end
```

Include this support file in spec/rails_helper.rb:

```
require 'support/devise'
```

In your rspec controller

```
# Create user however you want (e.g. using Factory Bot)
user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
login_as(user)

# Session will now be authenticated
visit root_path
```